# WSL2 docker-desktop: build fails with 'too many levels of symbolic links', /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop-data/data/docker not bound at /var/lib/docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, build, integration, wsl-2

I'm a newbie with docker, kubernetes, etc. I'm trying to set up a docker environment simply to test a Hello World! project (let's say in Node.JS to begin with) just to get an idea of how it works.

For the time being, my only viable temporary conclusion is: WSL2+docker does NOT work.

I spent several hours in stackoverflow and alikes only to discover that none seem to have achieved the basic purpose of docker: build a simple image (... then to deploy it, maybe with kubees&co and perform a basic curl test).

How come that it doesn't work out of the box? Is this a joke or is it just my situation that has some unattended issue?

**Steps**

I created a simple project:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir -p /dockerHelloJS

WORKDIR /dockerHelloJS

COPY index.js .

ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
```

index.js

```
const express   = require("express");
const app       = express();
const port      = process.env.HELLO_PORT || '8080';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Note: If there's a syntax error, please forgive me, as I haven't got the chance to test it obviously!...

Then, I naively tried the following command from within the project directory:

```
docker build .
```

That leads to an error pertaining to non existing directory structures or maybe even volumes and so on:

```
------
 > [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:latest@sha256:14bd39208dbc0eb171cbfb26ccb9ac09fa1b2eba04ccd528ab5d12983fd9ee24:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM node:latest
   2 |
   3 |     RUN mkdir -p /dockerHelloJS
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to register layer: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36a15fcda54210377bd4ae1b54d536119dca9b5b7558e33283a90d8bcab27305/merged: too many levels of symbolic links
```

Indeed:

```
$ namei /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36a15fcda54210377bd4ae1b54d536119dca9b5b7558e33283a90d8bcab27305/merged
f: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36a15fcda54210377bd4ae1b54d536119dca9b5b7558e33283a90d8bcab27305/merged
 d /
 d var
 d lib
   docker - No such file or directory
```

Well, frankly at this point, if /var/lib/docker doesn't exist, it merely means that WSL2 installation of docker is not working, end of story. It's not to the user to patch up a faulty business.

Just to cover things I did in the first place to get to this point:

1. I installed WSL2 from scratch with latest Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS at that time.
2. I installed Docker Desktop which created separate VMs.
3. I installed minikube in the Ubuntu VM as I wanted to test Kubernetes.
4. I configured so that docker *also* appears in aforementioned Ubuntu VM (but, why do we need two of them, the docker desktop and the ubuntu, hmm, that's strange).

[image: My VMs]

[image: Used WSL2 based engine]

[image: Enabled Docker on my Ubuntu VM]

Now, I could go down a series of questions on how to mount /var/lib/docker with bind to /mnt/docker-desktop-data/data/docker after creating a docker directory that didn't seem to have felt to be necessary to exist in the first place (which raises the question as to why). Why we need to have two docker installations: one in its proper VM, the other in any number of additional VMs, whether I should sudo my docker commands or not as /var/lib/docker would be a root owned mount point (or maybe it's already su-id'ed whatever), etc, etc. But who cares? There's only one valid question:

**Questions**

Has someone managed to docker build a project whatsoever from a WSL2 Linux VM? And at this point, even in another situation would be fine (I'll give it a try to docker build from my Windows main host instead with cmd).

And, if someone did, could you please be as so kind as to share?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, performing the docker build from a cmd shell with a copy of my test project in the Windows 10 environment leads to the same failure.